# Access a host from within a Docker container on Windows

Tags: windows, docker

I use Docker CE for Windows on latest Windows 10 and have built an image with a
script that runs a test against a web server.
(A litmus test suite for a WebDAV server to be exact, but I think the problem 
is general.)

I run the web server on a Powershell console:

```
> wsgidav -p 8080 -H localhost
21:04:19.107 - <13348)> wsgidav                     INFO    :  Running WsgiDAV/3.0.0a3 Cheroot/6.4.0 Python/3.6.5
21:04:19.107 - <13348)> wsgidav                     INFO    :  Serving on http://localhost:8080 ...
```

From another Powershell console, I run my script in a Docker container (using FROM alpine).
The script starts and tries to access the endpoint, but does not succeed:

```
> docker pull mar10/litmus
> docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 mar10/litmus http://gateway.docker.internal:8080
-> running `basic':
  0. init.................. FAIL (connection refused by `gateway.docker.internal' port 8080: Operation timed out)
```

I tried so far

- Using the `gateway.docker.internal` hostname
- using `-p PORT:PORT`
- using `--net=host`
- restarting the docker daemon (which interestingly sometimes also was neccessary to
  fix timeouts in `docker pull`)
- different IP addresses for the web server (127.0.0.1, localhost, 0.0.0.0, local IP)

Nothing worked so far (although the failure message may be different).
Maybe I just missed a working combination of the above, or any other trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, I was able to solve it by building the container with the `--network host` option and use a real IP of the client (instead of localhost or 0.0.0.0).

Details here: https://hub.docker.com/r/mar10/docker-litmus/